# How to search a value inside a properties file with format key=value using sell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need to search a value inside a file with this format:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

> Note: the value can have spaces.

I need to obtain the value of the key with a shell script.

I have this code:

```
myfile="./app.properties"
keyToSearch="EXAMPLE"
value=""
if [ -f "$myfile" ]     
   then
       echo "$myfile found."
       #Search the keyToSearch and obtain the value. 
else
   echo "$myfile not found."
fi
```

How I can search the key and obtain the value? For example with a while/do or similar.

Thanks!

Comment: it's simple with awk language

Comment: @mikea is similar but in my problem I have spaces, this is my main problem with the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
VAL=$(grep "$keyToSearch" "$myfile" | cut -d'=' -f2-)
```

The `"-f2-"` is basically asking for all the data after the first `"="`.

Check this: [cut(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)

In your case:

```
myfile="./app.properties"
keyToSearch="EXAMPLE"
value=""
if [ -f "$myfile" ]     
   then
       # echo "$myfile found."   # no noise on success
       #Search the keyToSearch and obtain the value. 
       value="$(grep "$keyToSearch" "$myfile" | cut -d'=' -f2-)"
else
   echo "$myfile not found."
fi
```

Comment: Thanks! and int example: key1=va lue (with space) how I can get only "va lue"?

Comment: Np, just understood what you wanted, this will match the key and get the value.

Comment: Thanks! work for me.